# Another way to write loops that do something different only on first iteration?

Tags: java, loops, iteration

Intro: Hi, first time poster and beginner java learner here and would like some help "cleaning up" my code. I have successfully printed the given output but was wondering if there are any other' simpler' ways to approach this exercise. I was thinking recursion but really don't know where to start.

#### The problem

- Write a loop that generates this output:

  ```
      1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377
  ```
- Your output *must* look exactly like the sample above – on one line, with commas and spaces as shown. Note that there is no comma at the end of the line.

#### What I've tried

My solution involves using three variables of type `int`: `first_num`, `sec_num`, `third_num` with a *for* loop and *if* statement.

```
// declare and initialize int first, sec, and sum
int first_num = 1;
int sec_num = 1;
int sum = 0;

//2
for (int i = 0; i <= 10;i++) {
    sum = first_num + sec_num;
    if (i == 0) {
        System.out.print(first_num + ", " + sec_num + ", ");
    }
    System.out.print(sum + ", ");
    first_num = sec_num;
    sec_num = sum;
}
System.out.print(sum);
```

Comment: search for "fibonacci"

Comment: your solution seems very good to me

Comment: You only need to track your current sum and the previous number. The sum of those two gives you the next number (1+1=2, 1+2=3, 2+3=5, 3+5=8, etc)

Comment: While we're at the subject – you should follow the Java Naming Conventions. Variable and method names are written in camelCase. So no underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more simpler version of your code, but it is not descriptive at first glance

```java
int first = 0;
int second = 1;

System.out.print(second);  
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    second = second + first;    // Now second equals to the sum of the first and old value of the second
    first = second - first;     // If subtract from second the value of first, we can get old value of the second

    System.out.print(", " + second);    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was trying to find a solution that didn't involve an if statement that had to be inside of a for statement. It appears as though I can put the first 2 printed numbers outside/before the for loop, and that would take care of the first iteration leaving the rest to be easily calculated. I'm having trouble understand the "+=" and second-first that you do, but it clearly gives me the right output.

Comment: I added some comments to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```java
int a, b, c, i, n;
n = 10;
a = b = 1;

System.out.print(a + ", " + b);

for (i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
    c = a + b;
    System.out.print(", ");
    System.out.print(c);
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

code from [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-program-to-print-a-Fibonacci-series)

with while loop:

```java
int a, b, c, i, n, count;
n = 10;
a = b = count = 1;

System.out.print(a + ", " + b);

while(count <= n -2) {
    c = a + b;
    System.out.print(", ");
    System.out.print(c);
    a = b;
    b = c;

    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This definitely looks better than what I had because it doesn't have as many checks to do. Could this also be done with a while loop or would it be more difficult to do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write a recursive function as trying to solve fibonacci sequence using recursion is a well known candidate for [dynamic programming](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall09/lecture_notes/lecture18.pdf).

You don't have to start the loop from 0. In fact you can start the for loop from the third number because you already know that the first 2 numbers are  both 1.

Here's the code:

```
int first_num = 1, int sec_num = 1;
int index = 2; // since you want to start generating numbers from index 3
int endIndex = 15; // total numbers in your list
int nextNum = 0;
while(index++ < endIndex){
    nextNum = first_num + sec_num;
    System.out.print(nextNum + ", ");
    first_num = sec_num;
    sec_num = nextNum;
}
System.out.print(nextNum);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for(int i = 0; i<=0;i++) {
    System.out.println("1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377");
}
```

Comment: Heh heh... Clever ;-)

Comment: Oops!! Forgot the quotes!

Comment: @JAMESLEE - And OP did ask for a "simpler" solution.